# Is there any external "Test Executor" GUI for Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am currently working on replacing an outdated test system that we're using at the company I work at with **Robot Framework**. The current system is used for function testing **embedded systems** that we produce. We are using an in-house software for executing the test scripts, which is good consider that the operators that are running the tests doesn't have a broad knowledge in programming. As it is right now they just need to know the name of the product and then press "Start test" in the GUI, which is exactly what we want.

What I've learned and seen now after spending some days playing around in Robot Framework is that there's no built-in GUI in some sort for executing test cases. I haven't even found a third-party solution for this, except using software like Jenkins, but that is not a good solution when the test needs to run locally on the computer where the operator is working. Running the tests from the terminal directly is not a good solution either, just because it's not that "user-friendly".

I've read about the [Robot Framework Public API](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/), which is so well documented that I could pretty easy build a new "Test Executor", but if there exists software that does this already I'm glad to hear about it!

I know that **RIDE** has the functionality to run selected tests via a GUI, but what I've experienced is that it's pretty easy to make horrible mistakes in that software. Don't get me wrong, RIDE is a awesome tool for creating .robot scripts, but it is not great as a "Test Executor", especially not when we really need to keep a constant production flow to meet our deadlines.

How should I handle this? Do you build your own tools for executing tests, or is it that I've missed something?

Comment: you can make use of eclipse or intellij IDE with the robot framework plugin installed and keep creating tests and perform CI/CD as well.

Comment: I am not aware of anything besides RIDE and the eclipse or intellij IDE plugins mentioned by @forkdbloke. My experience with non-tech users is that I ended-up explaining them that it would not be that hard to use the command-line, even if it looked not enough user-friendly for them at the beginning.

Comment: So I should probably build my own executor instead or use the ones you guys mentioned?

Comment: Users should not make `horrible mistakes` with RIDE. RIDE was created for non-programmers (manual testers). Each user can disable the `Editor` and `Text Editor` Plugins, thus only keeping the `Run` panel.
Other option, is for users to have a local Jenkins to run their tests.